# In BPMN, how can I express that two different lanes are doing different actions at the same time?

Tags: bpmn

- How to represent two lanes doing two different actions at the same time
- how to represent that a POOL of lanes contacts another POOL ?

Comment: Do you mean at the same time as in `parallel` or as in `same exact time`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, I would use parallel gateway so that following tasks placed in each lanes can be run concurrently.

For the second question, several solutions exist to represent exchange between pools:

- If you want a pool to start another one and wait (synchronous) for this new running pool to finish before continuing its execution you can use call activity.
- The main pool can also send for example a message or signal and target pool use a message or a signal start event. This allow to start another pool asynchronously. You can then use again message to define a synchronization point later in pool execution path.
- And a third option would be to use event sub-process. Based on the kind of event you choose for the sub-process it will interrupt or not the main process (see standard page 242 for the list of interrupting and non-interrupting event sub-process start events).